# Specific Attribute node replacement

Tags: xquery, marklogic

How to do node replacement in MarkLogic for a particular attribute? For example like below:

```
<chapters>
<title id="primary">first primary content</title>
<title id="primary">second primary content</title>
<title id="secondary">this is amy middle content</title>
<title id="terciary">this is amy last content</title>
</chapters>
```

I want like below:

```
<chapters>
<title id="primary">third primary content</title>
<title id="secondary">this is amy middle content</title>
<title id="terciary">this is amy last content</title>
</chapters>
```

I mean suppose `A.xml` file stored in MarkLogic database server that contain data like bleow:

```
<chaptermetadata>
<chapters>
<title id="primary">first content</title>
<title id="primary">second content</title>
<title id="secondary">This is middle content</title>
<title id="terciary">This is last content</title>
</chapters>
<chapters>
<title id="primary">fouth content</title>
<title id="primary">fifth content</title>
<title id="primary">sixth content</title>
<title id="secondary">This is new content</title>
<title id="terciary">This is old content</title>
</chapters>
<chaptermetadata>
```

Now, I want to replace a node in all the element `title` which contain attribute `@id='primary'` in all chapter like below:

```
<chaptermetadata>
<chapters>
<title id="primary">common content</title>
<title id="secondary">This is middle content</title>
<title id="terciary">This is last content</title>
</chapters>
<chapters>
<title id="primary">common content</title>
<title id="secondary">This is new content</title>
<title id="terciary">This is old content</title>
</chapters>
<chaptermetadata>
```

Comment: it's hard to understand what transformation you are requesting given the difference between the two code blocks

Answer (score 1):

If you are just getting started with XQuery and MarkLogic, http://developer.marklogic.com/learn/technical-overview and http://developer.marklogic.com/learn may help.

The best way to modify elements and attributes depends on the context, which you haven't supplied. I suppose the first question is "how do I select nodes by attribute?" A simple bit of XPath does that. For all chapters in the database:

```
/chapters/title[@id eq $id]
```

...or relative to a previously selected sequence of element(chapter)*

```
$chapters/title[@id eq $id]
```

If this is a database document, you could take it from there with the http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:node-replace and http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:node-delete functions. If the nodes are only in memory, see http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/typeswitch for guidance and examples on using an XQuery typeswitch or XSLT. At http://developer.marklogic.com/blog/tired-of-typeswitch there are more examples and comparison of typeswitch and XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon the examples you provided, it appears that you want to replace the `text()` for the first `title` element that has `@id='primary', and remove the other`title`elements with`@id='primary'`.

The following will achieve that, using [`xdmp:node-replace()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:node-replace) and [`xdmp:node-delete()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:node-delete) methods.

```
for $primary-title in doc("A.xml")/chaptermetadata/chapters/title[@id='primary']
return 
  if ($primary-title/preceding-sibling::title[@id='primary']) 
  then xdmp:node-delete($primary-title)
  else xdmp:node-replace($primary-title/text(), text{"common content"})
```